# Price calculation logical error

Tags: jquery

I'm already getting the total price.Problem is there is a flaw on my logic whenver I try to change the previous product type the price still increase.Here is the sample of my error.I can't explain it well but I got a working example.

Fiddle : 
[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rdanalasa/pyqhh45p/38/)

code :

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  var sum   = 0;
  var price = 0;
  var total = 0;
  var documents = "Documents (Up to 1kg)";
  var small = "Small (1-5kg 85cm)";
  var medium = "Medium (5-10kg 110cm)";

  function checkTotal() {

    var qty = $("input[name*='qty']");
    var piece_type = $("select[name*='piece_type']");

    qty.each(function(index) {

      var quantity = qty.eq(index).val();
      var selected = piece_type.eq(index).find(":selected").text();

      if (selected == documents) {
        price = 10;
        sum = parseFloat(quantity) * parseFloat(price);
      }

      if (selected == small) {
        price = 20;
        sum = parseFloat(quantity) * parseFloat(price);
      }

      if (selected == medium) {
        price = 30;
        sum = parseFloat(quantity) * parseFloat(price);
      }

      if(selected == selected){
          total += sum;
      }

      $("#wpc_total").text("Total : $" + total);
    });
  }
  $("select[name*='piece_type']").change(checkTotal);
});
```

Comment: You're not resetting `total` to zero

Comment: @Andreas but I needed to display it.

Comment: `checkTotal()` calculates the `total` value of the current state. Why would you add the sum of the current state on to the sum of the previous state?

Comment: yes, u need to display it, but u also need to clear it after it display, else, the value will keep add on

Comment: @madalinivascu I see sorry not very good in english.But could you try changing `piece type` couple of times.The price will also keeps on increasing.

Comment: @rainalasa see my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calculate the total each time you change a value:

```
      jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  var price = 0;

  var documents = "Documents (Up to 1kg)";
  var small = "Small (1-5kg 85cm)";
  var medium = "Medium (5-10kg 110cm)";

  function checkTotal() {

    var qty = $("input[name*='qty']");
    var piece_type = $("select[name*='piece_type']");
     var total = 0;//local total changes every time you change the values

    qty.each(function(index) {
      var sum   = 0;//reset the sum to 0
      var quantity = $(this).val()? $(this).val():0;
      var selected = piece_type.eq(index).find(":selected").text();

      if (selected == documents) {
        price = 10;
        sum = parseFloat(quantity) * parseFloat(price);
      }

      if (selected == small) {
        price = 20;
        sum = parseFloat(quantity) * parseFloat(price);
      }

      if (selected == medium) {
        price = 30;
        sum = parseFloat(quantity) * parseFloat(price);
      }

       total += sum;//no need for a if


    });
    $("#wpc_total").text("Total : $" + total);//show the total after the loop
  }
  $("select[name*='piece_type'],.number").change(checkTotal);
});
```

demo:https://jsfiddle.net/pyqhh45p/42/

Comment: I see you also saw why the piece type "documents" returning amount of 40.Could you tell me what was my error with the calculation also?

Comment: i have commented my code see the comments, you were not recalculating the total because the total and the sum where global variables